# How do I convince my colleagues not to implement IDisposable on everything?

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management, idisposable

I work on a project where there is a huge number of objects being instanced by a few classes that stay in memory for the lifetime of the application. There are a lot of memory leaks being caused with OutOfMemoryExceptions being thrown every now and again. It seems like after the instantiated objects ago out of scope, they are not being garbage collected.

I have isolated the problem to being mostly about the event handlers that are attached to the long-living object that are never detached, thus causing the long-living object to still have a reference to the out of scope objects, which then will never be garbage collected.

The solution that has been proposed by my colleagues is as follows: Implement IDisposable on all classes, across the board and in the Dispose method, null all the references in your objects and detach from all event that you attached to.

I believe this is a really really bad idea. Firstly because it's 'overkill' since the problem can be mostly solved by fixing a few problem areas and secondly because the purpose of IDisposable is to release any *unmanaged* resources your objects control, not because you don't trust the garbage collector. So far my arguments have fallen on deaf ears. How can I convince them that this is futile?

Comment: good luck my friend. deaf ears have a tendency to stay deaf.

Comment: These approaches you list that your colleagues are doing, are just a big hammer to an issue they don't fully understand.

Comment: The purpose of IDisposable is to release whatever needs releasing, managed or unmanaged. It is *primarily* used for releasing unmanaged resources, but I think it's entirely reasonable to release a dependency (e.g. removing an event handler) in IDisposable. That's not the same thing as implementing it in all types though.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this belongs on workplace.stackexchange.com but it's too old to migrate.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

By coincidence I just posted this comment elsewhere:

> An reference to an object being
>   incorrectly retained is still a
>   resource leak. This is why GC programs
>   can still have leaks, usually due to
>   the Observer pattern - the observer is
>   on a list instead the observable and
>   never gets taken off it. Ultimately, a
>   `remove` is needed for every `add`, just
>   as a `delete` is needed for every `new`.
>   Exactly the same programming error,
>   causing exactly the same problem. A
>   "resource" is a really just a pair of
>   functions that have to be called an
>   equal number of times with
>   corresponding arguments, and a
>   "resource leak" is what happens when
>   you fail to do that.

And you say:

> the purpose of `IDisposable` is to release any
>   Unmanaged resources your objects
>   controls

Now, the `+=` and `-=` operators on an event are effectively a pair of functions that you have to call an equal number of times with corresponding arguments (the event/handler pair being the corresponding arguments).

Therefore they constitute a *resource.* And as they are not dealt with (or "managed") by the GC for you, it can be helpful to think of them as just another kind of unmanaged resource. As Jon Skeet points out in the comments, unmanaged usually has a specific meaning, but in the context of `IDisposable` I think it's helpful to broaden it to include anything resource-like that has to be "torn down" after it has been "built up".

So event detaching is a very good candidate for handling with `IDisposable`.

Of course, you need to call `Dispose` somewhere, and you don't need to implement it on every single object (just those with event relationships that need management).

Also, bear in mind that if a pair of objects are connected by an event, and you "cast them adrift", by losing all references to them in all other objects, they don't keep each other alive. GC doesn't use reference counting. Once an object (or island of objects) is unreachable, it is up for being collected.

You only have to worry about objects enlisted as event handlers with events on objects that live a long time. e.g. a static event such as `AppDomain.UnhandledException`, or events on your application's main window.

Comment: "Unmanaged resource" has a pretty specific meaning that isn't covered by events. There's nothing special about events here - it's just one object having an unwanted reference to another. Nothing unmanaged going on at all.

Comment: (I agree with the points about it being entirely reasonable to implement IDisposable, and that not every type should implement IDisposable - but I vehemently disagree with your use of the term "unmanaged resource".)

Comment: I also agree that an event isn't a 'unmanaged resource' per se, but I have the same solution in mind of implementing IDisposable on classes where events must be detached and ONLY on these classes. 

Alas, it seems like despite all my arguments and some of the very intelligent responses I got from here, the powers that be stand firm on their decision. Sigh.... What can you do?

Comment: Save your strength for another day...

Comment: I guess it depends whether you take *unmanaged* to mean "that which isn't compiled to IL" or "that which isn't dealt with by the GC". To explain the full value of `IDisposable`, we can either say it's applicable to "unmanaged resources and also things written in managed code but that are otherwise like unmanaged resources", or we can broaden "unmanaged resources" to mean resources not cleaned up by the GC. As a user of a library I shouldn't care what language it's implemented in. I should care how to use it correctly, is it thread-safe, etc. That's why I prefer the broader definiton.

Comment: See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx - to me it says that an unmanaged resource is one not dealt with by the GC. Any interpretation more restrictive than that would discard a lot of the value of `IDisposable`.

Comment: Made an edit to clarify the scope of the term "unmanaged" here, with ref. to Jon's comment.

Comment: @Earwicker: I am also in disagreement over your use of the term "unmanaged resources."


The root distinction that drives what we clean up in Dispose() lies not specifically in whether the resource is managed or native, but whether we're cleaning up eagerly (Dispose() is called directly) or cleaning up due to object finalization. In the former you can clean up whatever you like, in the latter you don't know whether your managed references have already been disposed, so you don't touch them.

Comment: Cont'd: I think stretching the term "unmanaged resources" to include both native and managed resources is confusing and doesn't add clarity to the topic. More specifically, during finalization you cannot unsubscribe from an event because you don't know if the event object (or for that matter its owner) have been disposed--so describing the unsubscribe as "unmanaged" not only muddies the term but misses the point that one should only unsubscribe during eager disposal.

Comment: Cont'd: And eager dispose is the time when people generally understand they can clean up "managed resources," drawing further doubt as to why you would want to call them "unmanaged." Using a broader definition here doesn't seem to help. (Seriously, 600 characters isn't enough!)

Comment: Your perspective seems to be that finalization and dispose go together most of the time. That is unfortunately the impression given by a complete discussion like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243563/how-do-i-convince-my-colleagues-not-to-implement-idisposable-on-everything/1243597#1243597 - but they only go into finalizers in order to be complete. Actually finalizers are a niche thing, hardly any reason to write them these days. `IDisposable` is very frequently written without anything to do with finalizers. I'd urge you to look at how it's used in C++/CLI. Or...

Comment: ... how iterator methods use `IDisposable`. Not a finalizer in sight. The question of how to make best use of `IDisposable` therefore has little to do with finalization (the use of which is typically strongly discouraged.) I'd also encourage anyone still doubtful about this to think of their favourite examples of unmanaged resources, consider how those resources manifests themselves to the programmer, i.e. how you interact with them in code, and say to yourself: what is it about this resource that makes it "unmanaged", in the sense intended by the MSDN doc page for `IDisposable`?

Comment: A resource is two operations: build-up and tear-down, open and close, enter and exit, allocate/free etc. where we have to somehow limit the number of outstanding invocations of the first operation without a corresponding invacation of the second operation ("instances" of the resource). If simultaneous instances can overlap their lifetimes in any way ("orthogonality") and the operations are threadsafe, and the state of the resource doesn't itself depend on finalizable objects, we could use finalization to manage the resource (it's a tall order though).

Comment: Um... not sure why but the link in the comment to a "complete discussion" was suppose to go to this: http://www.bluebytesoftware.com/blog/PermaLink.aspx?guid=88e62cdf-5919-4ac7-bc33-20c06ae539ae

Comment: @Curt Nichols: The term "managed" in the phrase "managed resource" means that the cleanup function of the resource will be taken care of automatically via finalization if it wasn't taken care of manually before that.  An unmanaged resource is any resource (as defined in the answer above) which is not a managed resource; not all unmanaged resources are "native resources".

Answer (score 11):

Point them at [Joe Duffy's post about IDisposable/finalizers](http://web.archive.org/web/20130426072619/http://www.bluebytesoftware.com/blog/PermaLink.aspx?guid=88e62cdf-5919-4ac7-bc33-20c06ae539ae) - combined wisdom of many smart people.

I'm currently finding it hard to see a statement there saying "don't implement it when you don't need it" - but aside from anything else, showing them the complexity involved in implementing it properly may well help to dissuade them from it...

Unfortunately, if people won't listen, they won't listen. Try to get them to explain *why* they think they need `IDisposable`. Do they think the garbage collector doesn't work? Show them that it works. If you can convince them that it's doing no good (for most types) then surely they'll stop adding work for themselves...

As Brian says, implementing `IDisposable` isn't going to help with the event problem on its own - it needs to actually be *called* by something. Finalizers aren't going to help you in this case either. They really need to explicitly do *something* to remove the event handlers.

Answer (score 9):

Just implementing `Dispose()` across all types is not going to solve your problem. Remember that `Dispose()` is *not* automatically called and it has nothing to do with reclaiming managed memory.  In order to have any effect of your `Dispose()` methods, you need to call it in all relevant place - either explicitly or via `using`.

In other words just implementing `IDisposable` all around will not magically solve your problems cause the `Dispose()` methods will not be called unless you also change the usage of every type in your code.

However, I would *not* recommend implementing `IDisposable` on all your types, simply because it makes no sense. The interface is used to indicate that the type in question uses some resource, which isn't handled by the garbage collector.

Event references are handled by the garbage collector. You just need to unsubscribe if your publisher lives significantly longer than your subscribers. Once the publisher dies the subscribers will die as well.

Comment: Ok, I have left out one detail. The plan is to call dispose on all objects that are instantiated before they go out of scope.

Comment: That is surely a much greater task than just making sure you detach subscribers as needed.

Comment: @Brian - what, even with the `using` keyword?

Comment: @Earwicker: sorry, I'm not sure what you're asking. Please elaborate so I can clarify my answer if needed.

Comment: @Earwicker - the using keyword is the easy part. Implementing IDispose on all your classes is the great task

Comment: @Peter Rotham - hey, tell me about it. Actually the really hard part is pursuading Microsoft that implementing `IDisposable` deserves language support. The dream: http://smellegantcode.wordpress.com/2007/11/30/a-new-use-for-the-c-using-keyword/ - the reality: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=294208

Comment: An alternative is to use C++/CLI which already has this.

Answer (score 5):

I once helped a coworker out on a similar problem with OutOfMemoryException errors occuring (caused by events leaving object references hanging around). The first thing I did was run the code through FXCop, which highlighted Dispose wasn't called on an IDisposable class.

Modifying that code to be disposed fixed the issue. Perhaps you should recommend FXCop be used?

Perhaps find the code with the issue in the source repository, run FXCop on it- see if it highlights the issue (it probably will if it is caused by a .NET Framework class) and use that to convince your coworkers.

Answer (score 2):

It's a hard one to pull off, but I've found the best way to get people to do something you want is to let them think it's their idea. You know them better than me, but phrases like "If only there was a way to find out why the objects are hanging around so long" and "I wish I knew more about events holding on to objects" might be a starting point.

Comment: That's funny. For some reason it reminds me of Red Alert's "His Mind is Weak" phrase.

Answer (score 2):

Ask them if they would like to be forced to **turn off the motor after using a bicycle, even if there isn't a motor.**

Or if they would like to be forced to press a "turn off" button on their chair, desk, coffee cup and other stuff before their leave their workplace, even if there is nothing to be turned off.

Implementing IDisposable forces the user to explicitly tell the object when it is not used anymore. If this object does not need to clean up anything, it is just a unnecessary complexity.

By the way, IMHO unregistering events by implementing IDisposable is a suitable way to clean up events. There is something to "turn off".

Answer (score 1):

IDisposable is only meant to be used to release *unmanaged* resources (SafeHandles and the like), and the Dispose method propagates through the class heirarchy. It is not meant to try and get around bad unmanaged programming practices.

Comment: I don't think I'd go quite that far. It's for anything which needs orderly clean-up. For example, if you have an object pool you may want to implement `IDisposable` so that underlying objects can be released back to the pool... that needn't mean there are any unmanaged resources involved.

Comment: An event is an unmanaged resource.

Comment: @Earwicker: No it's not. What makes you think it is? (Not ManualResetEvent etc, but an event declared with the event keyword.)

Comment: @Jon Skeet: An resource is a pair of functions where calling the first creates a need to call the second.  A managed resource is one whose cleanup will be handled via finalizer if manual cleanup is neglected.  If an object subscribes to an event from a long-lived object, that creates a need for the object to unsubscribe.  Thus the event subscription is a resource.  Unless the subscriber does some complicated tricks, finalization will not clean up the event.  Thus it is not a managed resource.  A resource that is not a managed resource is an unmanaged resource.

Comment: @supercat: No, that's not the same kind of thing as an unmanaged resource in the traditional sense at all, IMO.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: A typical event subscription from a long-lived publisher certainly isn't a managed resource (since the GC's finalization mechanism won't clean it up), but it's something that needs to be taken care of before the event subscriber is abandoned.  If it isn't an unmanaged resource, what is it?  Certainly having Dispose suffice to clean up event subscriptions seems nicer than requiring someone to call something in addition to Dispose.

Comment: @supercat: It's "a potential memory leak" basically... just the same as anything else. If I call `foo.RetainHandleTo(this)` does that make it an unmanaged resource? No. It's just a leak. Yes, it's a good idea to clean it up - but the normal use of the term "unmanaged resource" is for non-memory resources such as file handles. I think it's worth considering them separately. In particular, it *does* make sense to have finalizers for classes which have direct handles to unmanaged resources, but a finalizer wouldn't help in the case you're describing.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I guess my point is that it's useful to have a term for the stuff that an IDisposable is supposed to clean up, and given the oft-quoted definition for IDisposable, the phrase "unmanaged resources" seems apropos; I can see that the fact that finalizers don't work with a direct-hooked event plan makes direct-hooked events somewhat different from other "unmanaged resources", but suppose the event hooks to an object which holds a WeakReference to the main object.  In that scenario, the main object could be collected but its finalizer would have to provide for unsubscription...

Comment: ...which would be somewhat complicated by the lack of any requirement that events provide an unsubscription method that can be run safely in a finalizer.  If the main object's events were wired like that, the main object would then be a managed resource (other code should call the main object's "dispose", but its finalizer would take care of the case where it doesn't) and the event subscription would be an unmanaged resource which was wrapped within it.

Answer (score 1):

Create duty on resolving one more OutOfMemoryException. When somebody resolves errors belong to others, it raises responsibility on own code.
At early stage of our project we have been recommended "flag of fool" - responsible on fatal error gets this flag for a day.

Answer (score 1):

Propose a solution that is much superior than their solution ;-)

For example, a simple alternative could be to use `WeakReference`s in the long-living objects to hold the references to the event handlers. This would require that the event handlers are referenced somewhere else as long as they're needed, but as soon as they'd go out of scope, they're garbage collected and the weak references can be removed from the long-living objects.

Comment: Yes, but how would you use weak references in event handlers since the reference is built into the delegate?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/greg_schechter/archive/2004/05/27/143605.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you register a handler with an event, then "unregistering" is just the sort of basic cleanup every object should do upon being destroyed.  If you don't have destructors in the language, then you have to define a method to call to tell the object it's going away.  That method should clean up the event handlers.

Isn't this what IDisposable is for?  Why would you need another solution if it's already there?  And why didn't those knuckleheads implement their objects correctly in the first place?  ;)

Answer (score 0):

An object needs to implement IDisposable if it needs to ensure that something *outside itself* which might *outlive it* gets cleaned up prior to being abandoned.  Some objects' properties are "connected" to other objects, so changing those properties will change the other objects; it is sometimes necessary to set those properties to null.  In vb.net, a "WithEvents" field is really a property which attaches and detaches event handlers, and consequently WithEvents fields in vb.net should be set to Nothing.  Note that it is generally not useful for an object to implement IDisposable purely for the purpose of nulling out its own fields.  There are a few cases where it may be helpful (e.g. if an object which has been around a long time holds a reference to a recently-created object, clearing the reference may allow the more recently-created object to be collected sooner than it would otherwise) but it's certainly not necessary.

What is necessary is to ensure that objects which need to clean up *other objects* implement IDisposable and ensure those other objects get cleaned up.  I am peeved at Microsoft for encouraging people to write code which abandons event handlers.  While it is true that one can get away with abandoning event handlers in cases where the event publishers don't outlive the subscribers, and such cases commonly occur with interlinked GUI elements, I really don't see any reason event shouldn't always be cleaned up as a matter of course.